# Does exec cause a context switch?

Tags: operating-systems

If we start a new process with

```c
exec('process-2')
```

Does this cause an immediate context switch in order to halt the current process and then start the new 'process-2'?

Edit: 
This is a theoretical question with no specific OS intended, but you suppose it's some UNIX like OS.

There is no specific details about exec, the only thing I know is that exec halts the current program execution and executes the other program.

Also the assumption here is that we are using a uni processor system.

Comment: (What does the specification say about `exec()`? What about a multi-processor environment?)

Comment: What OS are you on?